# Python Decorator Self-firing

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am fairly new to Python and have been learning about decorators. After messing around with Flask, I am trying to write some code that simulates their route handler/decorators, just to understand how decorators (with arguments) work.

In the code below, the route decorator seems to call itself once the script runs. My question is, how is it possible that `app.route()` gets called when i run this script, and what is really happening here? Notice i don't call my `index()` function anywhere directly.

```py
# test.py

class Flask(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.scriptname = name

    def route(self, *rargs, **kargs):
        args = list(rargs)
        if kargs:
            print(kargs['methods'])
        def decorator(f):
            f(args[0])
        return decorator

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET","PUT"])
def index(rt):
    print('route: ' + rt)
```

the above prints this in my terminal:

```py
$ python test.py
['GET', 'PUT']
route: /
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@app.route("/", methods = ["GET","PUT"])` is an executable statement: it calls the `route()` method of the app object. Since it's at module level, it will be executed when the script is imported.

Now, the *result* of calling `app.route(...)` is a function, and because you've used the `@` to mark it as a decorator, that function will wrap `index`. Note that the syntax is just a shortcut for this:

```
index = app.route(...)(index)
```

in other words, Python will call the function returned by `app.route()` with `index` as a parameter, and store the result as the new `index` function.

However, you're missing a level here. A normal decorator, without params, is written like this:

```
@foo
def bar()
   pass
```

and when the module is imported, `foo()` is run and returns a function that wraps `bar`. But you're calling your `route()` function *within* the decorator call! So actually your function needs to *return a decorator function* that itself returns a function that wraps the original function... headscratching, to be sure.

Your `route` method should look more like this:

```
def route(self, *rargs, **kargs):
    args = list(rargs)
    if kargs:
        print(kargs['methods'])
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped(index_args):
            f(args[0])
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

Comment: Notice that `index` is not being called. The decorating function is executed at definition time.

Comment: @That1Guy yes, just updating to explain that.

Comment: ah, ok, this is starting to make sense. When i replace my ```def route(self, *rargs, **kargs):``` with the one you've attached, i get ```TypeError: decorator() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given```

Comment: Sorry, `f` should have been the argument to `decorator`, not `wrapped`. The latter of course takes the arguments you're passing to `index`.

Comment: @daniel, but otherwise, i think you've answered what i was after. The difference between using a class method as a decorator vs stand alone function. thank you

Comment: Hmm, well it isn't to do with using a method vs a standalone function: this is just as much true as if you'd written `route()` as a standalone. The point is about using `@route` vs `@route(foo, bar)`.

Comment: oh, right, the inclusion of the parenthesis, as any function gets fired?

Answer (score -1):

Basically... `app.route(index, "/", ["GET", "PUT"])` is a function. And this is the function which is going to be called instead of index.

In your code, when you call `index()`, it calls `app.route(index, "/", ["GET", "PUT"])`. This starts by printing `kargs['methods']`, then creates the decorator function:

```
def decorator(f):
    f(args[0])
```

This decorator will call the decorated function (`f`) with one argument, `args[0]`, which here is "/". This prints `route: /`.

The best explanation of decorators I've found is here: [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python)

If you dont want the self-firing, you can define your decorator this way:

```
def route(*rargs, **kargs):
    args = list(rargs)
    if kargs:
        print(kargs['methods'])
    def decorator(f):
        f(args[0])
    return decorator

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET","PUT"])
def index(rt):
    print('route: ' + rt)
```

However, the `rt` argument of index will never be used, because `route` always calls `index` with `args[0]` which is always `\`...

Comment: in that example, they call ```print hello()``` at the end of the script. To my understanding, if they left that last line out, nothing should actually print though, right? So, are you saying that simply including the ```@app.route()``` above ```index()``` would auto fire? and if it were just say a regular decorating function like ```@route```, it would wait to be fired when ```index()``` is called?

Comment: Indeed, if the `print hello()` was not here then nothing would print.

Comment: As @Daniel_Roseman says, @app.route is an executable statement, because `app` is an instance of the class `Flask`. If you want it not to be executed, you need to define route as a standalone function (like `makebold` in the example), and not inside a class.