# Python Decorator executed on load/import

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to wrap my head around python's decorator. But there is something I don't understand. This is my code, my question is related to `func_decorate2` (decorator with parameter).

```
def func_decorate(f):
  def wrapper():
    print('wrapped');
    f() 
  return wrapper

@func_decorate
def myfunc1():
  print('func1')

def func_decorate2(tag_name):
  def _(f):
    print('underscore')
    return f
  return _

@func_decorate2('p')
def myfunc2():
  print('func2')

print('call func1')
myfunc1()
print('call func2')
myfunc2()
```

Will output :

```
underscore
call func1
wrapped
func1
call func2
func2
```

Why do I have `underscore` first in this example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `func_decorate2('p')` executes immediately and returns a decorator that is then itself immediately executed when the interpreter uses it to decorate `myfunc2`.

The trick to realize is the part following the `@` is just an expression. It doesn't have to be a function itself – it just needs to evaluate to one and the evaluation happens immediately on definition.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I posted my question too soon. There is another one with the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102930/python-decorator-self-firing

Answer (score 0):

Because func_decorate2 was wrong. If you want to use arguments in your decorator, you have to add one more def level

```
def func_decorate2(tag_name):
  def _(f):
    def _fun():
        print('underscore')
        return f
    return _fun
  return _
```

Comment: That's what I had a hard time understanding. I didnot see that the decorated was interpreted as `func_decorate2('p')(myfunc2)`